# rock wool absorption

Tags: acoustics

Hi,

I want to make my own bass trap and i can not find rock wool in 10 cm thickness.
In terms of absorption quality is there any difference to stack two 5cm rock wool plates together to form a 10cm rock wool thickness ? It's hard to find 10 cm rock wool really :(

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Two 5cm should be the same as 10cm. You could work a way of leaving an air-gap between the two 5cm layers though; that should make the sound 'absorption' higher than one 10cm layer.

Answer (score 0):

You won't find rockwool in 10cm slabs because they come cut in 5cm. What everyone does is stack two of them together. There's no difference at all!

Or as Skarik mentioned, you could put an airgap. I personally put the airgap behind my panels. If you do this, make sure the back doesn't have anything aside from your cloth. If you put a piece of wood, or some kind of membrane, it becomes pointless.

Answer (score 0):

We-heell, in my part of the world, Rockwool comes in 100, even 150mm thickness - ne ne neh!
Sorry - that aside, just make sure you don't accidentally compress the two 50mm slabs in your bass trap - or you will diminish the absorption effect. For that reason alone, making an air gap isn't a bad idea, even if it may be fiddly to actually implement.